# Circumventing "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider these two code examples

```
struct A {
    v: Vec<usize>,
    a: usize,
}

impl A {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        for _ in self.v.iter_mut() {
            self.f_mut();
        }
    }

    fn f_mut(&mut self) {
        self.a += 1;
    }
}
```

which produces the compile error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/binaries/main.rs:9:13
  |
8 |         for _ in self.v.iter_mut() {
  |                  -----------------
  |                  |
  |                  first mutable borrow occurs here
  |                  first borrow later used here
9 |             self.f_mut();
  |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

whereas this code

```
struct A {
    v: Vec<usize>,
    a: usize,
}

impl A {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        for _ in self.v.iter_mut() {
            self.a += 1;
        }
    }

    fn f_mut(&mut self) {
        self.a += 1;
    }
}
```

compiles just fine. Obviously these two pieces of code have identical behaviour so I am wondering if there is some way to get Rust to accept the first solution?

In my project I have some quite large for loops which I would like to refactor by splitting the body of the for-loop into separate function calls, but Rust doesn't allow me to do it.

That is, my more complicated code structured as example 2 compiles fine, but refactored into easier digestable functions as example 1 gives me the `cannot borrow *self as mutable more than once at a time` error.

Comment: An aside, but are you sure you don't just want `self.a += self.v.len()`? Or at the very least, as you don't modify the contents of the vector, `for _ in self.v.iter() { ... }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to borrow two disjoint fields when the borrow is behind a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154204/how-to-borrow-two-disjoint-fields-when-the-borrow-is-behind-a-method-call), [Rust not allowing mutable borrow when splitting properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699010/rust-not-allowing-mutable-borrow-when-splitting-properly)

Answer (score 4):

Your second example works because it performs a [splitting borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html).  The compiler can see that you're only borrowing `self.v` mutably, so it lets you borrow other fields on `self` mutably as well, since they don't overlap.

However, in the first example, `self.f_mut()` requires borrowing *all* of `*self` mutably (because it takes `&mut self`), which overlaps with the borrow of `self.v`, and is therefore disallowed.  This requires borrowing the whole value because the borrow checker only uses the *signature of the called function* -- it does not look into the function to see that it doesn't use `self.v`.  (If it did look into functions, then changing the body of a function without changing its signature could be an API-breaking change!)

Simply put, a function call is a "hard" boundary for the borrow checker.  By using a function call in the first example, the detail that only `self.a` is used is hidden from the borrow checker.